# Enable mod_headers, Dockerfile - Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, docker

The following has no effect;

```
# Dockerfile
FROM php:7-apache

RUN apt-get update && \
 apt-get install -y libxml2-dev && \
 docker-php-ext-install soap

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

# Enable apache mods.
RUN a2enmod php7.0
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod headers
```

i.e. the `mod_headers` module fails to load?

[image]

Do you know a way how to install the `mod_headers` module within `Dockerfile` ?

I tried;

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D",  "FOREGROUND"]
```

but then the container wouldn't start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN cp /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ && \
    cp /etc/apache2/mods-available/headers.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
```

That code will enable mod_rewrite and mod_headers.

Answer (score 0):

Set it in Apache config file with a sed replace. Like this:

> RUN sed -i 's/#LoadModule mod_headers/LoadModule mod_headers/g'
>   /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

You would obviously change the module name with the required module of yours... And the correct location of your httpd.conf as it might be in a different path.